# Python: How to use a variable before it is defined: For modularity and ease of reuse/editing, need to setup a series of conditions to check to iterate

Tags: python

```
# Trying to figure out how to specify Variable Structure (Dictionary) for Conditions and Revisions to be run in an Iterative Loop Run by a Function

entry_hierarchy = {'key_01': {'key_02': {'key_03': {'key_04': {'key_05': {'key_06':{'data_01': int(0), 'data_02': int(10), 'data_03': int(500), 'data_04': str('A105'), 'data_05': str('this is a phrase'), 'data_06': True, 'data_07': False, 'data_08': False}}}}}}}

revision_conditions_01 = {
                0: [
                    {
                    'CONDITION': data['data_01'] == 0 or data['data_01'] == 180 or data['data_01'] == 145 or data['data_01'] == 105,
                    'REVISION': 'Travel: Did you bill at 1/2 rate?'
                    },
                    {
                    'CONDITION': data['data_01'] == 90 or data['data_01'] == 72.5 or data['data_01'] == 52.5 and data['key_05'] == False,
                    'REVISION': 'Travel: First 30 minutes not included?'
                    }
                ],
                1: [
                    {
                    'CONDITION': data['key_08'] == False,
                    'REVISION': 'Add approval notation for travel.'
                    }
                ],
            }

def check_revisions(entry_hierarchy, keys_list, revision_conditions):
    # Iterative Loop in Function
    for key_01 in keys_list:
        for key_02, ref_nums in entry_hierarchy[key_01].items():
            for key_03, tk_ids in ref_nums.items():
                for key_04, dates in tk_ids.items():
                    for key_05, entries in dates.items():
                        for key_06, data in entries.items():
                            # Iterate Revision Conditions for Given data
                            for rev_key, revision_condition in revision_conditions.items():
                                if revision_condition[rev_key]['CONDITION']:
                                    update = revision_condition[rev_key]['REVISION']
                                    # Update entry_hierarchy and Add Revision to REVISIONS List
                                    entry_hierarchy[key_01][key_02][key_03][key_04][key_05][key_06]['REVISIONS'].append(update)

check_revisions(entry_hierarchy, [800,3000,250], revision_conditions_01)
```

I would like to be able to define the conditions_revisions variable in a different Python File (for ease of editing), however, it references variables that are only available inside the loop of the function that is called where the variable information is used.

I am new to Python (and some what programming in general).

I have come across exec() and eval() which I am guessing if I convert the values of the key 'CONDITIONS' to a string, I can then call the exec() or eval()...I am not certain evalwould work for this situation...in the loop of the function, however I am guessing as I have tried exec() in another program and was INSANELY slow.

I was also thinking maybe I could make a new definition which contains the conditions_revisions variable, but then I am calling a function inside a loop, which I understand to be a big no no and also very slow.

I could put setting the variable just before the loop inside the function, but that would defeat the purpose of creating a easily editable program.

I am wondering if there is a solution I am missing, or if I am just going about this entirely wrong? Or, if one the options I considered is the best, which one?

I am using Python 3.10

Comment: `eval` is dangerous, especially with data read from an external file.  The CLEAN way to do that is to have your `CONDITION`s be lambda functions.  Pass all the keys and necessary data as parameters.  It might not be pretty, but it would be flexible, and valid syntax.

Comment: Have you done the math to know how many loops you're going to run?  With 7 nested loops, you have the real potential to go exponential.  If each dict had 100 items, that's 100 billion loops.

Comment: I am not reading the eval() from an "external" file, it would be another python file, but would be edited by the programmer, so no concerns of executable code coming in from an outside source.

Comment: Sort of did the math...there are currently 7 of key_01, and 77 of key_02... Basically the entire dictionary is information relating to clients, for example key_01 is the client, key_02 is a number referencing an active something with client, key_04 refers to a person dealing with the client, key_05 is the date that person made entry, key_06 is the entry_id an the value of entry_id is a Dict with various info pertainig to that particular entry. # of key_02 is unknown, # key_04 unknown, # key_05 unknown, and # key_06 unknown.......soooo, maybe I need to find a better solution.

Comment: lanbda is new to me, thank you, I will have to google and learn about lambda, looking at your code I dont understand so thank you for leading me to something new to learn! But looking at the output, the output is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: I DO have the original data in non-hierarchical format, with each entry as a seperate non-nested dict. But I would have to loop through 10's of thousands of entries checking for client #, when usin gthe hierarchical structure, can just pull the key with proper client #'s. I created the hierarchical structure to be able to easily pull entries for a given client where a specific person entered the data, or a given date etc., so, maybe I should create seperate hierarchies for each process I run to make each process as efficient as possible....not likeI have to worry about memory usage....

Comment: a `lambda` is basically a one line unnamed function where the body is what is returned by the function when called. `def foo(bar): return bar == 1` is a named function and the same as an unnamed function lambda would be `lambda bar: bar == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your data, my intuition tells me that your `entry_hierarchy` might not be structured in a way that ultimately aligns with your use of it. I would definitely think about a flatter structure. However, your question can be solved by using a `revision_conditions_01` based on functions and in this case specifically based on lambdas.

an updated version of your code might be:

```
import json

# ---------------------
# We can also use a traditional named function instead of a lambda
# ---------------------
def cond1(data):
    return data["data_03"] >= 500
# ---------------------

revision_conditions_01 = [
    {
        "CONDITION": lambda data: data['data_01'] in (0, 180, 145, 105),
        "REVISION": 'Travel: Did you bill at 1/2 rate?'
    },
    {
        "CONDITION": lambda data: data['data_01'] in (90, 72.5, 52.5) and not data['key_05'],
        "REVISION": 'Travel: First 30 minutes not included?'
    },
    {
        'CONDITION': lambda data: not data['data_08'],
        'REVISION': 'Add approval notation for travel.'
    },
    {
        'CONDITION': cond1,
        'REVISION': 'some example condition has been met'
    }
]

entry_hierarchy = {
    'key_01': {
        'key_02': {
            'key_03': {
                'key_04': {
                    'key_05': {
                        'key_06':{
                            'data_01': int(0),
                            'data_02': int(10),
                            'data_03': int(500),
                            'data_04': str('A105'),
                            'data_05': str('this is a phrase'),
                            'data_06': True,
                            'data_07': False,
                            'data_08': False
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def check_revisions(entry_hierarchy, keys_list, revision_conditions):
    for key_01 in keys_list:
        for ref_nums in entry_hierarchy.get(key_01, {}).values():
            for tk_ids in ref_nums.values():
                for dates in tk_ids.values():
                    for entries in dates.values():
                        for data in entries.values():

                            for check in revision_conditions:
                                if check["CONDITION"](data):
                                    data.setdefault('REVISIONS', []).append(check["REVISION"])

check_revisions(entry_hierarchy, [800,3000,250, "key_01"], revision_conditions_01)

print(json.dumps(entry_hierarchy, indent=4))
```

when run this should give you:

```
{
    "key_01": {
        "key_02": {
            "key_03": {
                "key_04": {
                    "key_05": {
                        "key_06": {
                            "data_01": 0,
                            "data_02": 10,
                            "data_03": 500,
                            "data_04": "A105",
                            "data_05": "this is a phrase",
                            "data_06": true,
                            "data_07": false,
                            "data_08": false,
                            "REVISIONS": [
                                "Travel: Did you bill at 1/2 rate?",
                                "Add approval notation for travel.",
                                "some example condition has been met"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```